# Maximum likelihood estimate for a parameter $a$

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood

How to find maximum likelihood estimate for a parameter $a$ in distribution:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}  \frac{\left| x\right| }{a ^{2} }  &\text{for } x \in\left[ -a;a\right] \\0 &\text{for } x \not\in\left[ -a;a\right] \end{cases}$$

I did the following steps:
$$L\left( a;x_{1},...,x_{n}\right) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\left| x_{i}\right| }{a^{2}} = \frac{ \prod_{i=1}^{n}\left| x_{i}\right|  }{a^{2n}}$$
$$\ln L = -2n \ln a + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \ln  \left| x_{i}\right|$$
$$\frac{\partial \ln L}{\partial a} =  \frac{-2n}{a}=0$$

What to do next?

Normally (in other examples) i got something like this: $c*=\frac{1}{\overline{X}}$ where $c*$ is some estimated parameter, but here I will get $a*=\infty$, which is wrong IMO.

Comment: Is this for some subject, or for similar self-study from a text or similar? If so, could you please add the `self-study` tag?

Answer (score 3):

Your mistake is simply in taking the derivative and setting it equal to zero without thinking about what you're actually doing (*not all maxima are turning points*, he said, meaningfully). What you're actually identifying there would be a minimum.

Let

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \ln  \left| x_{i}\right|=K\,,$$

say, and *draw* the log-likelihood function.

... but take care about what the smallest possible value for $a$ is.